# How To Make WooCommerce Products In Specific Categories Redirect To Product Page (Not Add To Cart)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So after making my head bleed from beating it against a wall, I've come here for help.

The site I'm working on is [DomainCorral.com](http://domaincorral.com). What I'm trying to accomplish is make the products/domain names that are in the "Make Offer" category redirect to the product page, and NOT add the product to the cart, while leaving the other add to cart buttons as is.

I've figured out how to change the name of the buttons, but I still can't figure out how to make just the products in the Make Offer category redirect.

Would it be easiest to use JavaScript to accomplish this, or would it be better to use a WooCommerce hook?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

So I've found the code below that I need to use, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to ONLY the products in the "make offer" category.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
/*STEP 1 - REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON ON PRODUCT ARCHIVE (SHOP) */

function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');



/*STEP 2 -ADD NEW BUTTON THAT LINKS TO PRODUCT PAGE FOR EACH PRODUCT */

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo do_shortcode('<a class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" href="' . esc_attr($link) . '">More Info</a>');
}
```